# Azure Speech: Usage reporting on free plan (F0)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I have deployed a Speech resource (cognitive services) on Azure using the F0 plan (free tier). The free tier gives up to 5 hours per month. 
How can I check the current usage, letting me know how many minutes/hours have been spent already this month?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can see your free usage via the subscriptions page by following the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/check-free-service-usage

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only solution is to check on Cost Analysis on Azure Portal, then filter on your resource:

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_CostManagement/Menu/costanalysis

[image: Cost analysis]

But you will not get the item by minutes, but by price, then you can convert given the cost / minute. There might also be a delay between your real consumption and the impact on cost analysis.

Comment: The problem here is that since it's a free plan (S0), there is no corresponding cost. The cost analysis just shows 0€ for this component. What I'm trying to see is how much of the free quota has been used, and also how I would know upfront when to switch to a paying plan, before it actually hits the free limit and would start failing.